# LTspice temperature

Tags: resistors, ltspice, temperature

Is this rightly done when doing in LTspice?
Find out the effect of temperature in the range of -20°C to +100°C on the magnitude of the value of one of the resistances if its: a) the linear coefficient is 0.01 b) add a quadratic coefficient of 0.01 to the lin coefficient c) add exp coefficient tce=5
Can someone please check whether its correct?[image]

Comment: Filip - This is the second time I have needed to write to you today :( This question is a duplicate of part of [this previous question](/q/683362) which you asked earlier today and therefore *this* one is a (partial) duplicate. Writing duplicate questions is not allowed here, as I explained on that question. As you have decided to split that original multi-part question into separate parts, I have deleted it to prevent duplication, so that you can ask the individual parts (as you decided to do with this question). Please do not duplicate questions (or parts of questions) again. Thanks.